# Verificar Campos Vazios - Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tenho um campo inteiro e um campo data que não são obrigatórios e estão programados para aceitar NULL, porém quando envio os dados do formulário sem preencher eles o meu controller recebe o valor vazio ao invés de ignorar o campo, o que gera o erro:

> Incorrect integer value: '' for column vendedor_id

como posso resolver isso?

**Migration:**

```
 $table->integer('vendedor_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
 $table->date('data_venda')->nullable();
```

**Controller:**

```
$new = $this->repository->create($request->all());
```

**View:**

```
<div id="vendedor_id" class="form-group col-sm-4 opt">
    <label for="vendedor_id">Vendedor:</label>
    <select name="vendedor_id" class="form-control select2">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">User 1</option>
        <option value="2">User 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="data_venda" class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <label for="data_venda">Data:</label>
    <input type="date" name="data_venda" class="form-control">
</div>
```

No meu request tenho algumas validações para os campos obrigatórios, mas não inclui nada sobre esses 2 campos. Ex.:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'cnpj' => 'numeric|required|cnpj|unique:empresas',
        'razao_social' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Fornece a sua validação? e também aonde está fazendo esse código? acredito que tudo se resume na validação!!!

Comment: Precisa postar o trecho do código na sua pergunta, para ficar mais claro. Podem ser dois problemas diferentes (ou mais). Precisamos de mais detalhes.

Comment: Faça um submit sem enviar os valores obrigatórios. Debug com a função `dd` antes do insert.

Comment: Esse formulário está sendo enviado via Ajax? Eu já tive problemas assim quando usei `FormData`.

Comment: "vendedor_id" => ""
 "data_venda" => ""

Comment: Sim, é via Ajax @WallaceMaxters

Comment: Raylan de qualquer maneira esse erro ocorre porque estás a tentar inserir uma string num campo (coluna) da BD que é resevada para inteiros (`integer`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vou passar umas soluções abaixo que o próprio framework oferece:

## Model Mutators

É possível definir um comportamento para a definição de um determinado atributo de um Model em Laravel.

Por exemplo, para você não ter que definir a todo o momento condições de verificações de um campo no seu controller, você pode criar um `setter` específico para esses campos no seu Model.

Veja:

```
  public function setVendedorIdAttribute($valor) {
      $this->attributes['vendedor_id'] = ctype_digit($valor) ? $valor : NULL;
  }
```

Assim, toda vez que um valor vazio fosse passado, seria inserido como `NULL` no banco.

## Validação

De acordo coma  documentação do [Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-nullable), é possível, a partir dessa versão, definir uma validação `nullable` para determinado campo.

## Array_Filter

Outra solução seria utilizar `array_filter` que remove os valores vazios de um `array`.

```
$data = array_filter($request->all());
$new = $this->repository->create($data);
```

## Array_Map

Se você quiser apenas converter os valores vazios para `NULL`, você também pode usar `array_map` como solução:

```
$data = array_map($request->all(), function ($value) {
  return $value ?: NULL;
});
```

Comment: Eu pensei em dar também essa solução seria muito bom, o problema é que não sabemos o que o `respository->create` faz! se for `fill` vai funcionar

Comment: Funcionou também dessa forma! Das 2 formas na verdade

Comment: Acho que vou usar esse array_filter mesmo, fica tudo bem mais limpo e funciona perfeitamente

Comment: @RaylanSoares sempre prefiro soluções que "gastam menos".

Comment: O array_filter pode ser bom no create mas, no edit é prejudicial, e se eu quiser setar como `NULL`? @RaylanSoares

Comment: @VirgilioNovic se não quiser setar o valor como `NULL`, os valores simplesmente não estarão no `array`. Então aquele campo não seria atualizado. O `array_filter` remove valores vazios do `array`, ele não define para `Null`. Quando um campo é `nullable`, só o fato de ser omitido já faz ele ser definido para `NULL` (mas no caso do create, quando é insert a omissão mantém o que já tem).

Comment: @WallaceMaxters eu gravo create o número 1, e no editar eu seleciono `empty` querendo mudar o valor para `null` se ele não está no array não vai ter atualização !!!

Comment: Entendi, então se no update eu quiser voltar o valor pra Null não vai funcionar né

Comment: @RaylanSoares um, é verdade. Então nesse caso, você poderia converter também... Só um minuto.

Comment: @RaylanSoares com `array_filter` não ... só queria deixar claro que eu pensei no create e no edit, e no edit isso não seria válido. A opção seria o `setter` ( que tomo muito cuidado com ele ) ou verificar no controller

Comment: @VirgilioNovic como ele está usando o Repository, talvez fosse até mais rentável ele sobrescrever o método `create` e `update`, mas aí tem que ver como funciona essa treta, porque eu nunca mexi

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sim, mas, como eu disse não temos esse código em mãos, e talvez ele possa ser reescrito ou talvez não tudo vai depender, é um caso particular

Comment: Ambas as respostas foram muito esclarecedoras, fiz alguns testes aqui e vou usar a opção do setter. Obrigado @WallaceMaxters

Answer (score 5):

Se não for escolhido valor naquele `select` ele está enviando `""` ai mora o problema, precisa ser verificado antes de enviar para essa camada `repository`:

```
$data = $request->except('vendedor_id');
$data['vendedor_id'] = $request->input('vendedor_id', "") == "" 
                      ? null
                      : (int)$request->input('vendedor_id')
$new = $this->repository->create($data);
```

Comment: Isso resolve o problema, mas é meio gambiarra. Talvez o problema seja outro, mas o AP não descreveu direito.

Comment: Exato, podia ir ainda mais longe, e colocar `if(!is_numeric($request->input('vendedor_id')) { .... }`, o erro é gerado porque a coluna é `integer` e o Raylan está a enviar uma string

Comment: Então, o problema @WallaceMaxters está como ele está fazendo (talvez, porque não sei da intenção real), e não a minha resposta representar uma gambiarra. Gambiarra validar um campo que pode vir vazio ou então o número 1 ou 2 com um simples `if` não vejo como gambiarra.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic eu fiz um teste aqui. Realmente parece que o Laravel "deu esse mole". Quando o valor do "select" está vazio, ele envia uma string vazia mesmo.

Comment: Dessa forma funcionou, mas o ideal seria mesmo que o laravel mandasse um Null ou meramente ignorasse o campo

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, não é Laravel, é php mesmo, um input vazio é recebido como string vazia

Comment: @RaylanSoares é o seguinte, quando você manda um select e tem uma opção nele entre aspas duplas `""`, o `Laravel` entende que pode gravar um `empty` na tabela, mas, quando eu forço um `NULL` no campo ele entende que é pra gravar `null` é assim que ele trabalha! atualmente

Comment: @Miguel sim, mas o Laravel "deu mole" de não tratar isso direito. Acho uma boa dar a sugestão para eles melhorarem isso na próxima versão. Evita trabalho bracal.

Comment: Ha sim, tens razão @WallaceMaxters , é verdade

Comment: Entendi @VirgilioNovic, muito obrigado

Comment: @RaylanSoares esse código pode ser ainda melhorado, mas, ele te explica o porque do problema, é bom sempre passar qual é o problema que acontece.

Comment: Ambas as respostas foram muito esclarecedoras, fiz alguns testes aqui e vou usar a opção do setter. Obrigado @VirgilioNovic